# .init(activity); is showing error [android]

Tags: android

i am trying to implement  [ShineButton](https://github.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton) in my project . I have successfully synced the library to the gradle and added shine button in the xml.

now when i am trying to write the java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Kill bill", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    ShineButton shineButton = (ShineButton) findViewById(R.id.po_image2);
    shineButton.init(context);

  }
}
```

---

.init(**activity**); is showing cannot resolve symbol activity.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. We can't guess what or where you have any variable named `activity`

Comment: have you put this dependency in gradle compile 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.1.6'

Comment: you must pass context to shine button instead of activity

Comment: again look context is nowhere defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't literally copy the code verbatim, you read the documentation and object types supported by the method.

```
public void init(Activity activity) {
```

For example, I assume you are running that from an activity based on the usage of `findViewById`? Then you need "this instance of the Activity"

```
shineButton.init(this);
```

or an instance of an Activity if you were in a Fragment

```
shineButton.init(getActivity());
```

Comment: error message is gone ... but when i ran the app its crashing..:(

Comment: Feel free to create a new post, but include the logcat

Comment: i placed  <button> inside <ripple efect> in xml..thats why it crashed..now its working just fine,,,thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is in Activity use `shineButton.init(Activityname.this)`.

If it is in 
fragment use `shineButton.init(getActivity())`.
Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/
 and this https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
shineButton.init(context);
```

To:

```
shineButton.init(MainActivity.this);
```

`MainActivity.this` holds the instance of `MainActivity` class and can be used to initialise the `view`.

Comment: Please try to limit your posts to explain what you changed instead of making the poster try to spot the differences

Comment: error message is gone ... but when i ran the app its crashing..:(

Comment: can you tell me which exception is shown? stacktrace will be better if you can post it here.

Comment: i placed  <button> inside <ripple efect> in xml..thats why it crashed..now its working just fine,,,thanks for your help.